# AWK find exact match from environment variable

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to know how I can use AWK to find the exact match of an environment variable.

My environment variable is `ESSID="Super asdf"`

My file, which is also a variable (`$AIRODUMP_2G_LOG`), contains the following two lines (amongst many others):

```
E4-7A-19-80-01-CC, 2020-11-16 08:58:07, 2020-11-16 08:58:35,  8,  54, WPA2, CCMP, PSK, -81,       81,        5,   0.  0.  0.  0,  14, Super asdf,
EE-80-6B-70-C1-EF, 2020-11-16 08:58:07, 2020-11-16 08:58:36,  8,  54, WPA2, CCMP TKIP, PSK, -81,       79,        0,   0.  0.  0.  0,  18, Super asdf_EXT,
```

I currently have my AWK search function down to this:
`awk -F, '($14 ~ ENVIRON["ESSID"]) {print $0}' $AIRODUMP_2G_LOG`

With that search function it will both of those lines shown above, but I only really want the one without `_EXT` on the end. For the life of me I can't figure out how to use a search function where it ends with (`$`) just `Super asdf` using my environment variable. I know if I changed my search function to `awk -F, '$14 ~ /f$/ {print $14}' "$AIRODUMP_2G_LOG"` it will work, but I want to use an env-var inside of AWK instead.

EDIT:
Sorry, my code should have been `$14 == ENVIRON["ESSID"]` as explained in comment below.

Comment: `{print $0}` is awk's default action when only given a condition; you can thus just leave it out.

Comment: I actually wanted to print 1 and 4, but i omitted that in hast of writing a question. not too sure why i was marked down though, perhaps i should have mentioned that `==` didn't work for me?

Comment: Not my downvote; couldn't say. Don't worry about the occasional stray, unexplained downvote -- remember, each upvote earns a lot more rep than a downvote costs.

Answer (score 3):

Switch from `~` to `==` when you want an exact match.

```
awk -F',[[:space:]]*' '$14 == ENVIRON["ESSID"]' "$AIRODUMP_2G_LOG"
```

Comment: for some reason it still won't find it with `==`. No idea why, it's all there is in that string section

Comment: You have spaces, not just commas, in your data. Make it `-F',[[:space:]]*'`